# How to estimate harmonic mean?

Tags: estimation, harmonic-mean

Is there a way to estimate harmonic mean given other statistics such as arithmetic mean, variance, min, max, ... .

The goal is to estimate the mean incrementally as we get new data using a few counters.

Comment: You can use the AM-GM -HM inequality to get an upper bound.

Comment: Unfortunately, the GM bound is too loose in practical cases. Is there a way to augment it with something that improves the bound?

Comment: No, there isn't. Unless, you have more information about your data.

Comment: The HM cannot be below the minimum, so that's one possible lower bound. There are some additional bounds around that relate to these quantities, but if you want to do better than fairly weak bounds you'll probably need to supply more information about the variable in some way.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Glen, can you please give examples? Like what statistics would be useful and how?

Comment: Well, if you know the geometric mean you can get bounds for the HM from functions of the GM and the AM. If you have a lognormal distribution or you have a scaled and shifted Bernoulli($\frac12$) you can write the HM directly as a function of the GM and AM; weighted versions of the relevant inequalities would apply to two point distributions more generally, and so on. So for example if you knew you had a largish random sample from a lognormal, the lognormal identity would be a reasonable way to get an approximation. There's many possibilities depending on the information/assumptions available.

Comment: Actually if you have a lognormal or a gamma distribution you can write the HM directly in terms of the mean and variance so some distributional information like that may be very useful in terms of giving a reasonable approximation, if you have it. (You'd still want to make sure you didn't violate any obvious bounds along the way, but it wouldn't be likely)

Comment: Thanks Glen, Your solution makes sense. Unfortunately, I don't know the distribution of the input data. They usually look like almost equal, more like their log follows a normal distribution with small variance.

Comment: well, if their logs follows a normal, then by definition they are lognormal ... but anyhow, if you have the individual data, why do you need approximations? If you want online updating, then ask about that, and we can find update formulas for the harmonic mean.

Comment: You can look at it two ways, either online update the harmonic mean or keep some  stats that are enough to compute harmonic mean.

Comment: I thought what I said in the question. I want to estimate the mean incrementally. either update the mean itself in an online fashion or update something else (other means) and convert the final result to harmonic mean. Harmonic mean itself seems too expensive to update per item as it requires fractions.

Comment: At the end, I found that keeping an approximate distribution incrementally is easier than keeping harmonic mean and I can estimate the mean using the distribution easily.